# My @media queries aren't working on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to allow a container that holds five images per row to change the size of it's width if the browser width is smaller than the five images, including the margins etc.

I've added the following media query, and all works well when browsing on a desktop computer (resizing browser to less than 1080px in width)...The container changes width and the content is centered.

However, when browsing on mobile device (iPhone 4 and S4) it doesn't work. Thoughts?

**CSS**

```
.main-width {
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
    min-width: 960px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
    .main-width {
        max-width: 870px !important;
        min-width: 870px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is likely because you don't have a viewport set.

Place the following meta tag in the `<head>` element of your document.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For more information, read ["Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers "](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) - (mdn)

Answer (score 2):

You can use (max-device-width:1080px) instead. It passes viewport and applys on device width.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try this is a modified one that I use:

```
/* Media queries */

/* Desktop Resolutions */

/* 2k */
@media screen and (max-width: 2048px) {

}

/* 1080 HD */
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {



}

/* Wide SXGA/ Apple Powerbook G4 */
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {



}

/*  HDTV 720p/1080i monitors */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {



}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)  {



}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)  {



}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {



}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {



}


/* Device Width & Density */


/* iPad Mini */
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad 2 and 3 Landscape */
@media (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* iPad 2 and 3 Portrait */
@media (max-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* iPad 4 */
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* iPhone 4 */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {

}

/* iPhone 5 */
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* HTC One */
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Samsung Galaxy S2 */
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 534px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 */
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 */
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}
```