# Creating floating sidebars with a content area in the middle CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting my basic layout to work. I am new at HTML and CSS. How can I attain a 3 column setup on my website to allow for proper placing of ads along the sides?

I currently have 2 floating sidebars left and right and one content area that is not floating but there seems to be an invisible margin between the content area and the side bars.

[image: margin issue]

### HTML

```
<div class="float-left left-ad-space">
    <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
    <div class="float-right right-ad-space">
    <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
<div class="body-wrapper">
    <div class="filler">
        <div style="width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        @RenderSection("Featured", false)

    </div>

    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 1200px;
}

.body-wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
}

.left-ad-space {
    height: 500px;
    width: 160px;
}

.right-ad-space {
    width: 160px;
    height: 500px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.filler {
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to center the middle column.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLwSa/show)

```
.body-wrapper {
    width:900px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Aside from that, your calculations are a bit off because of the borders.

You could use [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) in order to include the element's border within it's dimension calculations. Most people just apply this property to all elements:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You would otherwise need to include this on the individual elements.

Comment: If I wanted to make my right column 300 px and my left 150px but subtract from the margin between the left column and the content when the browser is resized, is there a simple mod to this code to do that? Or would my best bet be media queries? A the moment I have my right column at 300px and it overlaps the content area as I resize the browser. I wish it would take the margin out of the left side and not the right.

Comment: @Adrian Media queries would be your best option. Just don't forget to include a [viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874043/my-media-queries-arent-compatible-with-mobile-devices/20874068#20874068)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this idea for your design. If you want more info look up html5 3 column layouts.

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="lcol"></div>
    <div class="ccol"></div>
    <div class="rcol"></div>
</div>

.colums { width:800px;} /*your wrappers width */
.lcol, .ccol, .rcol {
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.lcol { /*left column*/
    float: left; 
    width: 100px;
}
.ccol {/*center column*/
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
.rcol { /*right column*/
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```