# media screen not detected?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a stylesheet and for some reason my media queries are not being detected. When I resize my browser and `Inspect Element`, I'm still seeing the `1060px .container`.

here's the part of the stylesheet

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;    
    width: 1060px;
}


.container .section {
    margin-top:40px; 
    width:320px;
    margin-left:20px;
    float:left;
    height:480px;
    position:relative;

}



/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

    .container {
        padding-left:2%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 96%;
    }

    .container .section {
        width:96%;
        display:block;
        position:relative;

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `min-width` as opposed to `min-device-width` if you want it to be visible on non mobile devices. Also, make sure you have a viewport set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874043/my-media-queries-arent-compatible-with-mobile-devices/20874068#20874068

Comment: Thanks. i was able to make it work with this simple change!

Answer (score 1):

You define only smartphone media query. Outside this media query CSS, you must define CSS by this way for larger size.

```
/* 1080 HD */
@media screen and (max-width: 2048px) {
    .container {
      margin: 0 auto;    
      width: 1060px;
    }


    .container .section {
      margin-top:40px; 
      width:320px;
      margin-left:20px;
      float:left;
      height:480px;
      position:relative;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

.container {
    padding-left:2%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 96%;
}

.container .section {
    width:96%;
    display:block;
    position:relative;

}
}
```

And add following meta tag in  element of webpage document.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

above line point to a media query viewport, so its not find outside defined CSS.