# My media queries are not working for mobile

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, mixins

I have just launched my new website and it is not rezing for mobile. It seems to resize on my desktop when I drag the window down to size.

I used these below

```
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == desktop {
        @media (max-width:20000px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $point == tablet {
        @media (max-width:966px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $point == tablet-mini {
        @media (max-width:730px)  { @content; }
  }
  @else if $point == mobile {
        @media (max-width:499px)  { @content; }
  }
  @else if $point == mobile-mini {
        @media (max-width:342px)  { @content; }
  }
}
```

I then applied these to parts of CSS like this,

```
.name {
    @extend %lato-bold;
        background: url('/strongman.jpg') 50% 2px no-repeat;
        color: $white;
        font-size: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 30px 0 6px 0;
        font-style: italic;
        @include breakpoint(mobile) {
            font-size: 25px;
            padding: 30px 0 5px 0;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you including a viewport? See - [My @media queries aren't working on mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874043/my-media-queries-arent-working-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: I'm not no! off to google I go!